# determining the limit of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, for every $n > 0$ define:

$$a_n = \int_{\frac{-1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} f(x) \,dx$$

determine $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$

At first glance it would seem like the limit approaches zero, is that statement true?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's true! Since $f$ is continuous, its absolute value assumes its maximum on, say, [-1, 1]. Let $M$ be that maximum. Then
$$
\left| \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} f(x) dx \right| \le \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} |f(x)| dx \le \frac{2M}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the  limit is zero.

Hint:

if $F$ is an anti derivative of $f$,then $F$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another proof.
We know that since $f$ is continuous we may apply the mean value theorem for integrals which guarantees for each of the given intervals $[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ there is a number $c_n$ (depending upon $n$) such that
$$f(c_n)(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n})=\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^\frac{1}{n} f(x)dx$$
The intervals $[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ will shrink to the point $0$ in the limit (need to justify this by finite intersection property or something else but it's true)
so we see that the sequence $c_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Again since $f$ is continuous $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(c_n)=f(\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n)=f(0)$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2f(c_n)}{n}=0$ and we done.

Answer (score 0):

Mean value theorem for integrals :

$a_n=f(t) \int_{-1/n}^{1/n}1dx=(2/n)f(t)$, where $t \in [-1/n,1/n]$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(2/n) f(t)=$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (2/n)\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} $f(t) =0f(0)=0;$

Used: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(t) =0$, since

$t \rightarrow 0$, and $f$ is continuos.